How do you compute the net lift force location?
There are a lot of formula that give an approximate solution to the lift and drag forces associated with certain wing configurations.
What I'm curious about is how do you find where the net force is applied assuming a rigid body?
EX you're interested in designing a plane, you need to make sure the net lift force from the wings is applied to the COM so the plan stays level with minimal input.

If not otherwise specified, it is given in respect to the MAC

Would that be the center of gravity?  Keep in mind drag will also cause pitching moments, as well as the thrust vector. (Usually down, as adding power can cause the plane (aerodynamicly) to pitch up).
